# Laravel: paginating a fluent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, fluent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to paginate a page in my view like this:

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
    {{ $task->user_id }}
    {{ $task->client_id }}
    {{ $task->description }}
    {{ $task->duration }}
    {{ link_to_route('clients.show', 'View client', array($task->client_id), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
@endforeach
    {{ $tasks->links() }}
```

Using the following query in my controller:

```
$tasks = DB::table('tasks')
    ->join('users', 'tasks.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('clients', 'tasks.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
    ->select(array('tasks.description', 'tasks.duration', 'tasks.client_id', 'tasks.user_id', 'users.email', 'clients.name'))
    ->where('tasks.group_id', '=', $usergroup)
    ->orderBy('tasks.created_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(20);

    return View::make('tasks.index', compact('tasks'));
```

It shows the tasks fine but there's no pagination link showing up so I can't head over to the next batch of 20 results.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

I've tried @foreach($tasks->result as $task) in my view as suggested in http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=4092 but it gives me an error "Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$result"

Comment: @FDL the blade equivalent is {{ $tasks->links() }} which yep I have added above

Comment: Ah yep, didn't see that, apologies.

Comment: Are there more than 20 tasks???

Comment: Hi @HarryMartland there are 26 results in my database - also if I change the paginate number to something like 2 it still has the same result.

Comment: Have you got a custom view set in config? `app/config/view.php -> pagination` - or maybe deleted the default view?

Comment: My view storage path is the out of the box: 'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views'). Also, @FDL what do you mean by deleting the default view?

Comment: I mean 'pagination' option ("This view will be used to render the pagination link output, and can be easily customized here to show any view you like. A clean view compatible with Twitter's Bootstrap is given to you by default."), in `app/config/view.php` it defaults to `'pagination' => 'pagination::slider'` - is this still the same, or is it modified?

Comment: @FDL it's the same as out of the box: **'pagination' => 'pagination::slider',** ... =)

Comment: Can you dump `$tasks` in your controller with `dd($tasks);`. Make sure you're actually getting an instance of the Paginator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those playing at home - I discovered the answer to this:

The compact function is converting the object to an array. Change your return view method to:

```
return View::make('tasks.index')->with('tasks', $tasks);
```

And you're in the clear!

Another point - if you're using Bootstrap 3 RC1 like me you'll find that pagination breaks because of the way BS3 styles pagination - if you have that issue head over here for the solution: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2215

:)